# What's the difference between pkgs.visualstudio.com and pkgs.dev.azure.com?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We're using a private feed for our packages in Azure Artifacts, and to connect to this feed we use either `visualstudio.com` or `azure.com` URLs.

Format1:

`https://[org name].pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/[feed name]/nuget/v3/index.json`

Format2:

`https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[org name]/_packaging/[feed name]/nuget/v3/index.json`

The `Connect to Feed` button shows the Format1 URL but it fails on some PCs where the other format works well.

What's the difference between these two formats ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference between these two formats ?

The format 1: `https://[org name].pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/[feed name]/nuget/v3/index.json` is using the Azure DevOps old domain name(visualstudio.com).

The format 2: `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[org name]/_packaging/[feed name]/nuget/v3/index.json` is using the Azure DevOps new domain name(dev.azure.com).

When you navigate to the `Connect to Feed` option with the Old domain url, it will generate the Format1 URL.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Switch existing organizations to use the new domain name URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sep-10-azure-devops-launch#administration).

The two URLs are valid. To solve the connection issue, you need to check the firewall on your server.

You need to add the old domain urls to whitelist. You can refer to this doc: [Allowed IP addresses and domain URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#domain-urls-to-allow)